# Manipulating Administrative boundry of regions in R - changing country political boundry

Tags: r, maps

I am interested in joining the following provinces together: IRAQ ( Dohuk, Arbil, Kirkuk, As-Sulaymaniyah, Ardebil ) with the following provinces from Turkey( Erzurum, Elazig, Diyarbakir, Malatya, Sanliurfa, Kars, Gaziantep ) and from IRAN ( Kordestan ). The data comes from GDAM.

```
library("knitr")
library("pagenum")
library(zoom)
######################################################################################################

##Plot of the middle east
oceanCol = rgb(7,0,30,maxColorValue=255) 
cc<-c("Jordan","Syria","Lebanon","Israel","Palestine","Iraq","Iran","Georgia","Azerbaijan",
      "Turkey","Saudi Arabia","Kuwait","Bahrain","Qatar","United arab Emirates","yemen")

country<-countrycode(cc,"country.name","iso3c")

me<-vector("list",length(country))

for (i in 1:length(country)){ me[[i]]<-getData("GADM", country=country[i],level=1)}
map<-rbind(me[[1]],me[[2]],me[[3]],me[[4]],me[[5]],me[[6]],me[[7]],me[[8]],me[[9]],me[[10]],
            me[[11]],me[[12]],me[[13]],me[[14]],me[[15]],me[[16]])


plot(map,xlim=c(35,60),ylim=c(20,42), col="#ffffff",bg=oceanCol,border="black", 
     main ='State Creation and The Future Boundries Of The Middle East')

text(map, map$NAME_1, cex=0.3)

mtext("Source: TTTTTT July 2017",side=1,line=1)
legend("bottomright", legend=c("©TTTT"),col=white, cex=0.5, bty="n")
addnortharrow(pos="topright",scale=0.5,lwd=1, border="white",cols=c("white","white"), text.col="white")

pagenum(text="TTTT", date=TRUE,
  x=.95, y=.95, just =c('right','top'))

box()
#zm()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your desired output?

Comment: Desired output: A map of the ME based on Ethnic composition. For example, Kurdistan region is a combination of administrative regions from north-west Iran, South-East Turkey, Northern Iraq, and Northern Syria. This country is "Kurdistan". How to remove the boundaries and create a New State and give it a new name?

Comment: You should describe this in your Question. Furthermore, I think this is not about plotting the data but a previous step of data manipulation. Therefore, try to come up with an example and try to define the problem. Otherwise your question could be flagged as "too broad" or "off-topic", since it is more of a geopolitical problem than one of programming.

Comment: Thanks Loki for the feedback. In the map@data, there is a column:  "NAME_1 " contains names of the provinces. I am interested in joining the following provinces together: IRAQ ( Dohuk, Arbil, Kirkuk, As-Sulaymaniyah, Ardebil ) with the following provinces from Turkey( Erzurum, Elazig, Diyarbakir, Malatya, Sanliurfa, Kars, Gaziantep ) and from IRAN (  Kordestan ). This creates the region.   Maybe it is easier to give it all the same colour, but then how do you give it a single name? thanks

Comment: You should outline that in the Q as precise as you can. Please click on "edit" at the bottom of your post and edit the Q. Also please try to give a minimal example of your code that leads to the problem. IMHO, the knitr library for example is not needed for such a spatial problem.